# Mirage server GETs data but POST fails

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I have the mirage models:

```javascript
// mirage/models/country.js
import { Model, belongsTo, hasMany } from 'miragejs';

export default Model.extend({
    name: '',
    iso3166_1_alpha3: '',
    capitol_city: belongsTo('city', {inverse: null}),
    cities: hasMany('city', {inverse: 'country'})
});
```

and:

```javascript
// mirage/models/city.js
import { Model, belongsTo } from 'miragejs';

export default Model.extend({
    name: '',
    country: belongsTo('country', {inverse: 'cities'})
});
```

and the serializer:

```javascript
// mirage/serializers/application.js
import { camelize, capitalize, underscore } from '@ember/string';
import { JSONAPISerializer } from 'miragejs';

export default class ApplicationSerializer extends JSONAPISerializer
{
    alwaysIncludeLinkageData = true;

    keyForAttribute(attr) {
        return underscore(attr);
    };
    keyForRelationship(modelName) {
        return underscore(modelName);
    };
    typeKeyForModel(model) {
        return capitalize(camelize(model.modelName));
    };
};
```

When I run the tests:

```javascript
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { setupTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import { setupMirage } from 'ember-cli-mirage/test-support';

module('Unit | Mirage | mirage models', function (hooks) {
  setupTest(hooks);
  setupMirage(hooks);

  test('it retrieves the country', async function (assert) {
    const server = this.server;
    let city = server.create('city', { id: '1', name: 'Paris' });

    server.create(
        'country',
        {
            id: 'FR',
            name: 'France',
            iso3166_1_alpha3: 'FRA',
            capitol_city: city
        }
    );

    let response = await fetch('/api/countries')
    assert.strictEqual(response.status, 200, "Should have created the model");
    let json = await response.json();
    assert.deepEqual(
        json,
        {
            data: [
                {
                    type: 'Country',
                    id: 'FR',
                    attributes: {
                        name: 'France',
                        iso3166_1_alpha3: 'FRA',
                    },
                    relationships: {
                        capitol_city: {data: {type: 'City', id: '1'}},
                        cities: {data: []},
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    )
  });

  test('it creates the country', async function (assert) {
    const server = this.server;
    server.create('city', { id: '1', name: 'Paris' });

    let response = await fetch(
        '/api/countries',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Countent-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(
                {
                    data: {
                        id: 'FR',
                        type: 'Country',
                        attributes: {
                            iso3166_1_alpha3: 'FRA',
                            name: 'France',

                        },
                        relationships: {
                            capitol_city: { data: { type: 'City', id: '1'} },
                            cities: { data: [{ type: 'City', id: '1'}] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    );

    console.log((await response.json()).message);
    assert.strictEqual(response.status, 201, "Should have created the model");
  });
});
```

The first one passes and the second one fails with the message:

> ```
> Mirage: You're passing the relationship 'capitol_city' to the 'country' model via a POST to '/api/countries', but you did not define the 'capitol_city' association on the 'country' model.
> ```

How can I get Mirage to recognise the `capitol_city` attribute on the model?

Answer (score 1):

Mirage is opinionated with regards to the format of attributes and expects the attributes to be in `camelCase` (and not `snake_case`).

Unfortunately the [Ember CLI Mirage model relationships documentation](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/data-layer/relationships) does not mention this expectation and all the examples use single-word attributes. Even more unfortunately, Mirage will work with `snake_case` attributes for simple `GET` requests and when directly creating models through the API; it is only when you make a request to `POST`/`PUT`/`PATCH` a model into the server that it fails and the message will (confusingly) refer to the snake case attribute which has been defined. (See [the Mirage source code](https://github.com/miragejs/miragejs/blob/b965b8a058523dac0d6ab4792826887154e25368/lib/route-handlers/base.js#L76) for where it fails.)

To solve it, convert the attributes to camel case:

```sql
// mirage/models/country.js
import { Model, belongsTo, hasMany } from 'miragejs';

export default Model.extend({
    name: '',
    iso31661Alpha3: 0,
    capitolCity: belongsTo('city', {inverse: null}),
    cities: hasMany('city', {inverse: 'country'})
});
```

and change it in the tests as well:

```sql
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { setupTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import { setupMirage } from 'ember-cli-mirage/test-support';

module('Unit | Mirage | mirage models', function (hooks) {
  setupTest(hooks);
  setupMirage(hooks);

  test('it retrieves the country', async function (assert) {
    const server = (this as any).server;
    let city = server.create('city', { id: '1', name: 'Paris' });

    server.create(
        'country',
        {
            id: 'FR',
            name: 'France',
            iso31661Alpha3: 'FRA',
            capitolCity: city
        }
    );

    let response = await fetch('/api/countries')
    assert.strictEqual(response.status, 200, "Should have created the model");
    let json = await response.json();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
    assert.deepEqual(
        json,
        {
            data: [
                {
                    type: 'Country',
                    id: 'FR',
                    attributes: {
                        name: 'France',
                        iso3166_1_alpha3: 'FRA',
                    },
                    relationships: {
                        capitol_city: {data: {type: 'City', id: '1'}},
                        cities: {data: []},
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    )
  });

  test('it creates the country', async function (assert) {
    const server = (this as any).server;
    let city = server.create('city', { id: '1', name: 'Paris' });

    let response = await fetch(
        '/api/countries',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Countent-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(
                {
                    data: {
                        id: 'FR',
                        type: 'Country',
                        attributes: {
                            iso3166_1_alpha3: 'FRA',
                            name: 'France',

                        },
                        relationships: {
                            capitol_city: { data: { type: 'City', id: '1'} },
                            cities: { data: [{ type: 'City', id: '1'}] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    );

    console.log((await response.json()).message);
    assert.strictEqual(response.status, 201, "Should have created the model");
  });
});
```

---

However, once you convert it to camel case then the attribute `iso31661Alpha3` does not get formatted correctly in the output so you have to manually change the serializer for the country model:

```javascript
// mirage/serializers/country.js
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';

export default class CountrySerializer extends ApplicationSerializer
{
    keyForAttribute(attr: string) {
        switch(attr)
        {
            case 'iso31661Alpha3': return 'iso3166_1_alpha3';
            default: return super.keyForAttribute(attr);
        }
    };
};
```

Once the attributes are in the correct case then it will work.